# Haskell - How to generalize across Float and Double

Tags: haskell

I have a simple type class used to represent continuous probability distributions, with one instance. I'd like to write the typeclass and formulas as general as possible so that, for example, I could chose between Float or Double as appropriate.

This does not compile:

```
class ContinuousDistribution d where
    ppf :: Floating a => d -> a -> a

data Uniform = Uniform
     { lowerBound :: Float
     , upperBound :: Float
     } deriving (Show)

instance ContinuousDistribution Uniform where
    ppf d q = (1.0 - q) * lowerBound d + q * upperBound d
```

Producing

```
stats.hs:10:27: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Float’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          ppf :: forall a. Floating a => Uniform -> a -> a
        at stats.hs:10:5
    • In the second argument of ‘(*)’, namely ‘lowerBound d’
      In the first argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘(1.0 - q) * lowerBound d’
      In the expression: (1.0 - q) * lowerBound d + q * upperBound d
    • Relevant bindings include
        q :: a (bound at stats.hs:10:11)
        ppf :: Uniform -> a -> a (bound at stats.hs:10:5)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Specifying the types in the type-class declaration compiles, but restricts me to Float.

```
class ContinuousDistribution d where
    ppf :: d -> Float -> Float

data Uniform = Uniform
     { lowerBound :: Float
     , upperBound :: Float
     } deriving (Show)

instance ContinuousDistribution Uniform where
    ppf d q = (1.0 - q) * lowerBound d + q * upperBound d
```

What's the canonical way to modify the typeclass so I can use Float or Double as needed?

Comment: While this is pretty easy to achieve, I'd recommend you give some thought to whether you really need it at all. There's generally not much point to using any other type but `Double` for numerical calculations in Haskell – `Float` isn't really faster on modern processor unless you use SIMD instructions (which GHC doesn't do by itself), and not more memory-efficient unless you use unboxed arrays.

Comment: Good point. Was really just using the example to grok typeclass vs type interactions, and the parameterized data class pretty much nailed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let your distribution parameters data structure be parameterized by the `Floating` instance:

```
data Uniform a = Uniform
     { lowerBound :: a
     , upperBound :: a
     } deriving (Show)

class ContinuousDistribution d where
    ppf :: Floating a => d a -> a -> a

instance ContinuousDistribution Uniform where
    ppf d q = (1.0 - q) * lowerBound d + q * upperBound d
```